# Qu’est-ce que « on ne m’a rien jeté » veut dire ici ?

Tags: sens, québec, paroles-de-chanson

Ceci est une deuxième question sur la chanson « le couteau » chantée par « mes souliers sont rouges ».  Celui qui parle à la première moitié de l’extrait est un clochard qui prie un métayer de lui prêter un coup de main. Les propos qui la suivent viennent du métayer.

1. Mon bon Monsieur, on ne m'a rien jeté, le long des routes.
2. Je voudrais avec votre chien partager deux, trois croûtes !
3. Si depuis ce matin tu rôdes, tu dois être affamé.
4. Voici du pain, des crêpes chaudes, voici du lard fumé !

La seule chose que je ne comprends pas ici, c’est le mot jeter. Je pense que le gueux veut dire que les gens qu’il a croisés ne lui avaient pas donné de nourriture. Il est toutefois aussi pensable que cette phrase ne contient pas de langage figuré, et qu’il veut seulement dire que tous les gens qu’il a vus n’ont rien jeté sur le chemin : Le clochard pourrait avoir pensé que les autres les autres voyageurs le trouveraient ignoble. Il en pourrait avoir conclu qu’ils ne voudraient donc pas lui donner de la nourriture de façon chaleureuse.

J’espère que vous pouvez m’expliquer le rôle que « jeter » joue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*jeter* est ici pour *donner*, avec une connotation de mépris.  L'image que j'ai c'est donner de la nourriture à un animal en la jetant par terre.  La mention du chien par après renforce cette image.  (Voir aussi la BD *le chasseur de prime*)